# PHP/SQL fetch multiple values on SUM SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit of a complicated issue to explain but here goes:
I have an SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
SUM(time.timein),  
time.reasonforabsence
WHERE 
staff.id = time.staff_id 
AND 
staff.department_id = department.id  
AND 
(staff_name LIKE '%$staffsearch%') 
GROUP BY 
staff.id 
ORDER BY 
time.dateadded
ASC;
```

From this statement I need to pull the values `time.reasonforabsence` but as this is text and the statement is grouped, I cannot seem to do this. Does anyone know if there is a way for me to pull them possibly into a PHP array.

The `time.reasonforabsence` has multiple possible values.

Sorry for the vagueness I am writing this in a rush. Let me know if there is anymore info needed and I will add it tomorrow.

Comment: Can you post information about what your table structure looks like and what is the current and desired output of your query ?

Comment: You could probably use GROUP_CONCAT for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is return an aggregated string

```
SELECT 
SUM(time.timein),  
GROUP_CONCAT(time.reasonforabsence)
...
```

You can optionally use DISTINCT if you don't want repeated reasons. On php you'll have split them

Comment: Thanks! That worked but I have another question but this may be better on another thread. Now I have the values `"Holiday Full Day,Sick Full Day,Sick AM,Sick PM,Holiday Full Day,Holiday AM,Holiday PM,Absent Full Day,Absent AM"`. How can I break them up in PHP. I tried: 
(`$rowcsv['reasonforabsence']` is the string), 
`$reasonforabsence = $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'];`
`$reasonsforabsence = str_replace('"','',$reasonsforabsence );`
but I just get the same output. Im trying to output this to csv but since the string is in quotes I am just getting the string in 1 cell.

Comment: Try `explode( ',', $rowcsv['reasonforabsence'] )` and you'll get an array with the results

Comment: And remove that `$reasonsforabsence = str_replace('"','',$reasonsforabsence );`. That ain't doing anything

Comment: For this array to be formatted correctly I would need to `$reasonforabsence = implode('", "', $reasonforabsence);` but this still doesnt work. I get `"Holiday Full Day"",""Sick Full Day"",""Sick AM"",""Sick PM"",""Holiday Full Day"",""Holiday AM"",""Holiday PM"",""Absent Full Day"",""Absent AM"` I would have thought that the new quote would have created each value in a new cell but its just not working. Frustrated or what...

Comment: Maybe you should open a new question. I'm kind of lost on what exactly is your problem